# Use MultiValueDictionary instead of Dictionary with NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, multi-value-dictionary

Currently, I have this code, which works, getting a foodList:

```
var myDictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
myDictionary .Add("RefId",1);
myDictionary.Add("Type", "fruit");
var foodList = this.factoryService.GetMyService()
                    .GetByCriteria(sortOrder, NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.AllEq(myDictionary));
```

I want to use [MultiValueDictionary](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary/) so as to gather more than one Type.

```
var multiValueDictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.MultiValueDictionary<string, object>();
multiValueDictionary.Add("RefId",1);
multiValueDictionary.Add("Type", "fruit");
multiValueDictionary.Add("Type", "vegetable");
multiValueDictionary.Add("Type", "fungus");

var foodList = this.factoryService.GetMyService()
                    .GetByCriteria(sortOrder, NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.AllEq(multiValueDictionary));
```

That last line doesn't compile because MultiValueDictionary does not implement IDictionary, giving the error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.MultiValueDictionary' to
>   'System.Collections.IDictionary'

How can I do this?

Comment: `AllEq` requires an `IDicationary` based type, `MultiValueDicationary` does not inherit from IDicationary.

Comment: Not sure if this will work with NHibernate but you could try this: https://gist.github.com/mxmissile/b8c630046afba43c55365dea32e6c7e7

Comment: @mxmissile: I see what your thinking, but that gives a runtime error `Type mismatch in NHibernate.Criterion.SimpleExpression: Type expected type System.String, actual type System.Collections.Generic.List`. So it is expecting a `String` as a value not a `List`.

Comment: Why not just use the `In()` method for the `Type` column?

Comment: Not sure what you're saying ... can you point to code example?

Comment: Not sure how GetByCriteria is implemented, but I updated that gist above to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AllEq` implementation](https://github.com/fredericDelaporte/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Criterion/Restrictions.cs#L723) is simply:

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Apply an "equals" constraint to each property in the key set of a IDictionary
> /// </summary>
> /// <param name="propertyNameValues">a dictionary from property names to values</param>
> /// <returns></returns>
> public static AbstractCriterion AllEq(IDictionary propertyNameValues)
> {
>     Conjunction conj = Conjunction();
>
>     foreach (DictionaryEntry item in propertyNameValues)
>     {
>         conj.Add(Eq(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value));
>     }
>
>     return conj;
> }
> ```

So for your multi-value case, you could cease putting it in the dictionary and manually add it afterward:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
myDictionary.Add("RefId", 1);

var filter = (Conjunction)Restrictions.AllEq(myDictionary);
filter.Add(Restrictions.In("Type", new [] {"fruit", "vegetable", "fungus"});

var foodList = this.factoryService.GetMyService()
    .GetByCriteria(sortOrder, filter);
```

Of course if you now only have `RefId` to put in your dictionary, better simplify it:

```
var filter = Restrictions.Conjunction();
filter.Add(Restrictions.Eq("RefId", 1));
filter.Add(Restrictions.In("Type", new [] {"fruit", "vegetable", "fungus"}));

var foodList = this.factoryService.GetMyService()
    .GetByCriteria(sortOrder, filter);
```

Now if you want an `AllIn` handling multi-values, code it:

```
public static AbstractCriterion AllIn<TValue>(
    MultiValueDictionary<string, TValue> propertyNameValues)
{
    var conj = Restrictions.Conjunction();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, IReadOnlyCollection<TValue>> item in propertyNameValues)
    {
        if (item.Value.Count > 1)
        {
            conj.Add(Restrictions.In(item.Key, item.Value.ToArray()));
        }
        else
        {
            conj.Add(Restrictions.Eq(item.Key, item.Value.FirstOrDefault()));
        }
    }

    return conj;
}
```